# How do I update my kernel

Tags: linux, android, kernel, linux-kernel, selinux

So I have this kernel source and I need to update the selinux version, in order to make it support android 6.0 the last thing it supported was 4.4, how do I do that? https://github.com/Packmaan7144/kernel_nvidia_s8515 All help is appreciated